# Calculating mean of raster layers in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, statistics

I used cell statistics in ArcMap to produce mean raster file out of 6 rasters but cloud and no data areas is obvious in result. How can I homogenize my raster?

[image: mean of 6 rasters]

Comment: What do you mean by "homogenize my raster"? What is your desired outcome? Are you trying to mask out the clouds and NA values?

Comment: when i mask out the clouds and turn them to NoData and then calculate mean of layers it looks like the top of the image . i mean the no data areas have different values in final raster . this is my problem

Answer (score 2):

First make sure that all values you want ignored are set to "NoData". You can do this with the SetNull Function, for your clouds you will need a cloud mask. If this is Landsat imagery that is available from the USGS site. Otherwise you will need to implement some sort of cloud classifying methods - that is another question. 
Then, when you use [Cell Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cell-statistics.htm) make sure you select, or pass as the final argument "DATA". This means only layers which have data at that location will be used. All layers which are "NoData" i.e. missing values and clouds, will be ignored.